# how to configure local and remote repository in settings.xml for maven

Tags: maven, dependencies, settings, archiva

I have my own organization internal repository for which i would like to use:

```
    <repository>
        <id>archiva.default</id>
        <url>http://my.org.repo:8000/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
    </repository>
```

I also needed remote repository to get latest version of maven-resource-plugin, maven-compile-plugin, jboss etc.

Can someone please suggest me how to configure settings.xml so that maven downloads the dependencies that are available in internal repository, if the dependencies are not available in internal repository then get it from remote repository.

Comment: Maven does that by default.  Did you try the build and have it fail?  If so, how is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/userguide/using-repository.html:

```
<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>Repository Proxy</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <!-- ******************************************************* -->
  <!-- repositories for jar artifacts -->
  <!-- ******************************************************* -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      ...
    </repository>
    ...   
  </repositories>
  <!-- ******************************************************* -->
  <!-- repositories for maven plugins -->
  <!-- ******************************************************* -->
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      ...
    </pluginRepository>
    ...   
  </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
...
```